# SQL Server - How to change sub-queries into joins for query optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

this is my sample query.

```
SELECT * FROM SW_TBL_PROFILE_AGENTS agent
WHERE( 
    agent.MSISDN in(SELECT Source_Wallet_ID FROM SW_TBL_TRANSACTION WHERE Source_Wallet_ID = agent.MSISDN)
    OR
    agent.MSISDN in (SELECT Dest_Wallet_ID FROM SW_TBL_TRANSACTION WHERE Dest_Wallet_ID = agent.MSISDN)
)
```

Now i need to change this subquery to joins, since there is an 'OR' , i am confused.

Comment: Since it’s joining one table just make a join using OR for the clauses?

Comment: Obviously!!! Thanks You!!!

Answer (score 1):

it is easier to use `EXISTS`

If you looking at just one condition

```
WHERE 
    agent.MSISDN in (SELECT Source_Wallet_ID FROM SW_TBL_TRANSACTION WHERE Source_Wallet_ID = agent.MSISDN)
```

Basically this can re-written as

```
WHERE (SELECT * FROM SW_TBL_TRANSACTION t WHERE t.Source_Wallet_ID = agent.MSISDN)
```

To add another condition for `Dest_Wallet_ID`, just use `OR` inside the `EXISTS` query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SW_TBL_PROFILE_AGENTS agent
WHERE EXISTS
( 
       SELECT *
       FROM   SW_TBL_TRANSACTION t
       WHERE  t.Source_Wallet_ID = agent.MSISDN
       OR     t.Dest_Wallet_ID   = agent.MSISDN
)
```

Comment: i would rather prefer using joins, since this query is too slow.

Comment: Sure, if you do prefer to use joins

Comment: @AayushRajopadhyaya what makes you believe JOIN's will be faster? Since MSSQL can stop searching after the first hit with `WHERE EXISTS()` it has to do less work and thus is likely to be faster. Additionally you risk creating doubles when sticking to `JOIN`.